# how to add the navigator for base line highchart to the xaxis from the highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

i have the base line highchart with the trend line and points ..now i want to add Range for the xaxis in the Single line series highstock ...

```
This is Jsfiddle please observe  :
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/7/

And this is the Highstock :

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo

or

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/

How to add the Navigator for first jsfiddle graph that is having the in the highstock ..

please help

Thanks !!

Edited code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<title>RNA</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=Edge'/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

</body>

<script type="text/javscript">
$(function () {
    var sourceData = [
        [0, 99.43],
        [1, 99.40],
        [2, 99.24],
        [3, 99.40],
        [4, 99.21],
        [5, 99.45],
        [6, 99.41],
        [7, 99.18],
        [8, 99.36],
        [9, 99.31],
        [10, 99.38],
        [11, 99.20],
        [12, 99.38],
        [13, 99.32]
    ];
    var dates = ['18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '18-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '19-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14', '20-Jul-14'];
    $('#container').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'RNA - CP ( Radio Network Availability - Customer Perceived)',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.series.name == 'Series 2') {
                    return false;
                }
                //console.log(this.point.extprop);
                var s = 'The value for <b>' + this.x +
                    '</b> is <b>' + this.y + '</b>';
                if (this.point.extprop) {
                    s += 'for <b>' + this.point.extprop + '</b>';
                }
                return s;
            }
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        navigator: {
            enabled: true
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                rotation: 90,
                align: "left",
                formatter: function () {
                    return dates[this.value];
                },
            },
            tickInterval: 1
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            //align: 'right',
            //verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'RNA',
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                y: 99.43,
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 1,
                y: 99.40,
                extprop: 'flood'
            }, {
                x: 2,
                y: 99.24,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 3,
                y: 99.40,
                extprop: 'flood'
            }, {
                x: 4,
                y: 99.21,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 5,
                y: 98.45,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'flood'
            }, {
                x: 6,
                y: 98.41,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 7,
                y: 99.18,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'flood'
            }, {
                x: 8,
                y: 99.36,
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 9,
                y: 99.31,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'flood'
            }, {
                x: 10,
                y: 99.38,
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 11,
                y: 99.20,
                color: 'red',
                extprop: 'flood'
            }, {
                x: 12,
                y: 99.38,
                extprop: 'power issue'
            }, {
                x: 13,
                y: 99.32,
                extprop: 'flood'
            }]
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            marker: {
                enabled: false
            },
            /* function returns data for trend-line */
            data: (function () {
                return fitData(sourceData).data;
            })()
        }],
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });

});

</script>

</html>
```

yes , this is script and one issue when i load in the browser the graph is not displaying and also when i inspect element no errors are there ..i cant able to find the issue ..in the browser its showing empty page..@pawel .
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean bottom navigator? It's supported only in Highstock. In Highcharts you can use [this workaround](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail). Or maybe you just want to set `xAxis.min` and/or `xAxis.max` ?

Comment: Yes...i want to add the navigator in the x-axis ...please help in the jsfiddle ..

Comment: in my jsfiddle ..where i have to add the code ..?

Comment: could you please tell me ..http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/7/  in this fiddle where i have change the code to add the navigator..i

Comment: Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/hj22wbe5/16/ - as I said, Highstock license is required for that navigator.

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus , you have included the Highstock library and in the navigator ...after the 1st Jan ...00:00:00:0005,00:00:00:00010 ...what are these values ? instead of this how to pass the dates overall dates of x-axis

Comment: It's problem with using categories on xAxis. Remove them, and the replace in each of points: `x` value. Now x-value is index of category, while should be timestamp in ms.

Comment: categories on xaxis ?

Comment: i have seen the code ...? but where i have to change the xaxis value ..0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7...these are the xaxis values ..how to remove the dates and time stamp in the navigator..?

Comment: Well, you don't have 'categories' on xAxis, but how would you call getting index (x-value) from series and then finding proper date from 'dates' variable? Anyway, right now you have: `x:1`, right? Change that to `x:12314234234`, where the number is **timestamp in ms** for that point.

Comment: Hi @PawełFus . .i have added your script and also i include the issue ..its not displaying graph on the browser ..no errors after inspect element..please tell

Comment: No errors? I can see a lot of errors in JS console.. anyway, example for you: http://jsfiddle.net/wza3b25v/ - note: I won't write full code for you, you know that? ;)

Comment: Thanks ...But this graph is not at all opening in the browser ..why ???

Comment: Which browser? Works fine for me.

Comment: any browser is not opening ...i am trying in chrome and mozilla and explorer...on graph is displaying ...?

Comment: Sorry, this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wza3b25v/ really works for me..

Comment: yes, this link works for me , but with trend line link is not displaying in the browser..?

Comment: Sorry, which one doesn't work?

Comment: For this .. jsfiddle.net/wza3b25v  you have'nt add the trend line .,...can you please add the trend line ..i have tried but fitdata()   function passed two arguements ...?

Comment: Just realized that you are trying to use jqPlot plugin for trendline in Highcharts. You know that these two libraries are different? ;) Anyway, tried to add this, but I get this result: http://jsfiddle.net/wza3b25v/1/ I guess the problem is that you are using duplicated points for the same day..